# Powershell Script to get last 2 days IIS log files and check size difference or growth of files

Tags: html, powershell, iis, logging

Working on Powershell Script to get last 2 days IIS log files and check size difference or growth of files and email or generate a html email with values.

i did few steps but stuck when getting difference between 2 files of logs and also the html part.

here is my code,

```
# Set your backup path
$BackupPath = "D:\log files\"

# Get the log file created today
$BackupToday = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath -Filter "*.log" | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date} | %{[int]($_.length/1KB)} 

# Get the log file created yesterday
$BackupYDay = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath -Filter "*.log" |  Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date} | %{[int]($_.length/1KB)}

# Compare the two files based on the size
$compare = ($BackupYDay - $BackupToday)

Write-Host($BackupToday)
Write-Host($BackupYDay)
Write-Host($compare)
```

Comment: Remove the `bash` tag since your question has nothing to do with it. You might want to add `batch` if appropriate.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you need help with. Can you post a minimal representation of what you have tried and what does not work please? Is it guaranteed that you will only have one file per day?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure with what you mean by *"and email or generate a html email with values"*.
For that, have a look at the [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

If what you want to email is as simple as a string showing the difference (if any) in size of the two files, you could do something like this:

```
# Set your backup path
$BackupPath = "D:\log files"

# get the logfiles and select only the latest two
$logNewest, $logBefore = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupPath -Filter "*.log" -File | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 2
$sizeDiff = $logNewest.Length - $logBefore.Length

$difference = switch ([math]::Sign($sizeDiff)) {
     1 { 'File {0} is {1:N2}KB larger than file {2}'  -f $logNewest.Name, [math]::Abs($sizeDiff / 1KB ), $logBefore.Name }
    -1 { 'File {0} is {1:N2}KB smaller than file {2}' -f $logNewest.Name, [math]::Abs($sizeDiff / 1KB ), $logBefore.Name }
     0 { 'File {0} and file {1} are of equal size'    -f $logNewest.Name, $logBefore.Name }
}

Write-Host $difference
```

Result:

> File Today.log is 0,01KB larger than file Yesterday.log